# How to the slope of the line between two points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, linear-regression

I have a question that should be straightforward but I have been really struggling figuring it out.

I have two experimental groups with 10 subjects. For each member I plotted a regression line for the time spent in a zone (`sum_cum`) between a start point (p1) and the end point (p3) of the experiment.

This is my dataframe:

```
  group animal period week   sum_cum   period_cont
  <fct> <chr>  <chr>  <fct>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1 chr   chr1   p1     0         0            0
2 chr   chr1   p1     1       128.           0
3 chr   chr1   p1     2       106.           0
4 chr   chr1   p3     0       10.265         1
5 chr   chr1   p3     1       46.425         1
6 chr   chr1   p3     2       4.366          1
```

Using geom_smooth I plotted a mean line of best fit. I would now like to find the slope of these mean lines as well as to compare if they are statistically different. You can see what I mean in the picture below (where 0 = p1 and 1 = p3 on the x axis):

[image]

Effectively, I would like to calculate the slope for the two mean lines for each individual week, as well as to compare them statistically (using Ancova, probably? But if I should use something different any advice is also appreciated.)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this. I've used method = "lm".

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~group, ~animal, ~period, ~week, ~sum_cum, ~period_cont,
  "chr", "chr1", "p1", 0, 0, 0,
  "chr", "chr1", "p1", 1, 128., 0,
  "chr", "chr1", "p1", 2, 106., 0,
  "chr", "chr1", "p3", 0, 10.265, 1,
  "chr", "chr1", "p3", 1, 46.425, 1,
  "chr", "chr1", "p3", 2, 4.366, 1
) |> 
  group_by(group, animal, week) |> 
  nest() |> 
  mutate(slope = map_dbl(data, ~ coef(lm(.x$sum_cum ~ .x$period_cont))[2]))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#> # Groups:   group, animal, week [3]
#>   group animal  week data              slope
#>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <list>            <dbl>
#> 1 chr   chr1       0 <tibble [2 × 3]>   10.3
#> 2 chr   chr1       1 <tibble [2 × 3]>  -81.6
#> 3 chr   chr1       2 <tibble [2 × 3]> -102.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>